# Laravel auth vs Passport vs Sanctum

Tags: laravel, authentication, token

What is the difference between `Laravel auth`, `Passport` and `Sanctum` and when are they used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Passport provides` a full `OAuth2` server implementation for your `Laravel application` in a matter of minutes. It is therefore necessary to have a brief knowledge of `OAuth2`.

`Sanctum` it is a simple package to issue `API tokens` to your users without the complication of `OAuth`. Sanctum uses `Laravel's` built-in `cookie` based `session` authentication services.

In a small application use Sanctum. it's simple and easy

`Auth` (`Authentication`) is the process of identifying the user credentials. In web applications, authentication is managed by sessions which take the input parameters such as email or username and password, for user identification. If these parameters match, the user is said to be authenticated.

Refrences:

- [Auth](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_authentication.htm)
- [Passport vs Sanctum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812883/laravel-sanctum-vs-passport)

Hope it helps..

Thanks.

Comment: I would add that **Sanctum** can only be used when API and SPA are under the same domain name. And although **Passport** can be used between different domain names, the user of a SPA needs to be redirected to Laravel to sign in before being redirected to the SPA. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For me, **Sanctum** is a *lighter auth system* to used in SPA under the same domain as the API. while **Passport** (OAuth2) allows to sign in from a SPA to another domain, and user is redirected to backend to login, which is *complicated*. **Token and JWT** just seem older and more *difficult*.